# Can this be vectorized (numpy)?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have a list of feature vectors, and would like to compute the L2 distance of a feature vector to all other feature vectors, as a uniqueness measure. Here, `min_distances[i]` gives the L2 norm of the i-th feature vector.

```
import numpy as np

# Generate data
nrows = 2000
feature_length = 128
feature_vecs = np.random.rand(nrows, feature_length)

# Calculate min L2 norm from each feature vector
# to all other feature vectors
min_distances = np.zeros(nrows)
indices = np.arange(nrows)
for i in indices:
    min_distances[i] = np.min(np.linalg.norm(
        feature_vecs[i != indices] - feature_vecs[i],
        axis=1))
```

Being O(n^2) it's painfully slow, and would like to optimize it. Can I get rid of the for-loop / vectorize this such that `min` and `linalg.norm` are called only once?

Comment: Yes, it can be vectorised. (That answers your question as posted)

Comment: @coldspeed By using `np.vectorize` ?

Comment: No, I would suggest broadcasting the arithmetic. If you want a solution, I recommend a [mcve] with sample input array and expected result. Thanks.

Comment: Did the posted solution work for you?

Comment: @Divakar, yes, thank you so much, but please see my additional question below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Here's one with [`cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) -

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist,pdist,squareform

d = squareform(pdist(feature_vecs))
np.fill_diagonal(d,np.nan)
min_distances = np.nanmin(d,axis=0)
```

**Approach #2**

Another with [`cKDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html) -

```
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

min_distances = cKDTree(feature_vecs).query(feature_vecs, k=2)[0][:,1]
```

Comment: Ok great, this works. But I have a different case, where I need to selectively exclude certain pairs in the distance matrix, not just the diagonal. How would I do that? For example, in my original example I would change it to  `for i in indices: min_distances[i] = np.min(np.linalg.norm(feature_vecs[uids[i] != uids] - feature_vecs[i], axis=1))` where `uids` is a vector having same length as `feature_vecs`

Comment: @izak Edit the question and add that into it alongwith appropriate sample data. It's hard to read off a comment.

Comment: never mind. I solved it myself, and it's not really essential to the question itself. Your solution works well.